# How to call multiple functions in javascript and have them display?

Tags: javascript, function, program-entry-point

I'm trying to call multiple functions at once and have them displayed on the screen. CalculateSum function is able to display correctly. The error message is quotient not defined. I've looked at CalculateQuotient function, I don't understand what I'm missing. Is there a different way to call the function?

```js
function CalculateSum(numberOne,numberTwo) {
  var sum = 0;
  sum = (numberOne + numberTwo);
  return sum
}

function CalculateDifference(numberOne,numberTwo) {
  var difference = 0;
  difference = (numberOne - numberTwo);
  return difference
}
function CalculateProduct(numberOne,numberTwo) {
  var product = 0;
  product = (numberOne * numberTwo);
  return product
}
function CalculateQuotient(numberOne,numberTwo) {
  var qoutient = 0;
  quotient = (numberOne / numberTwo);
  return quotient

}

function Main() {
// variables for this part of the program
  var numberOne = 0;
  var numberTwo = 0;
  var output = "";
  
 
// get value from users  
  numberOne = prompt("Enter first nummber");
  numberTwo = prompt("Enter second number");
 
  numberOne = Number(numberOne);
  numberTwo = Number(numberTwo);
  

// call function and capture return value
  sum = CalculateSum(numberOne, numberTwo);
  difference = CalculateDifference(numberOne, numberTwo);
  product = CalculateProduct(numberOne, numberTwo);
  quotient = CalculateQuotient(numberOne, numberTwo);
  
// create output statement
  output = "The sum is " + sum + ".";
  output = "The difference is " + difference + ".";
  output = "The product is " + product + ".";
  output = "The qoutient is " + qoutient + ".";

  document.write(output);
}

// We have to call our Main function explicitly or it won't work.
Main();
```

Comment: As soon as you can, move away from using `document.write`, `alert`, and `prompt`.

Comment: You have typos in your code (`qoutient`). Moreover, you're overwriting several times your `output`.

Comment: // create output statement
output = "The precentage growth is " + CalculateSum + ".";

The above line of code should be:

// create output statement
output = "The percentage growth is " + sum + ".";   This a different way to stop the program from overwriting? I haven't tried it yet. Would I include both? I'm so confused. Never done multiple functions before.

Answer (score 0):

`quotient` is misspelled as `qoutient` when you concatenate your output string together. So the interpreter is attempting to evaluate a variable that hasn't actually been defined

Answer (score 0):

The variable name is "quotient" and not this "qoutient"
just change that.

Thanks